# Cross product of vector functions

Tags: calculus, cross-product

I was trying to make sense of a problem when I stumbled upon this on yahoo answers. I was just wondering if it was correct. If it is, can you please maybe explain why?

${\bf r}'(t) = \langle -5 \cos t, -5 \cos t, -4 \sin t \rangle$

${\bf r}''(t) = \langle 5 \sin t, 5 \sin t, -4 \cos t \rangle$.

${\bf r}'(t) \times {\bf r}''(t) = \langle 20, -20, 0 \rangle$.

Comment: I'm learning this exact same thing in class. Are you in my class??

Comment: I don't know.... U of M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${\bf r}'(t) \times {\bf r}''(t) = \langle -5 \cos t, -5 \cos t, -4 \sin t \rangle \times \langle 5 \sin t, 5 \sin t, -4 \cos t \rangle = \begin{vmatrix} {\bf i} & {\bf j} & {\bf k} \\
-5 \cos t & -5 \cos t & -4 \sin t \\ 5 \sin t & 5 \sin t & -4 \cos t \end{vmatrix}$$ $$= 
\begin{vmatrix} -5 \cos t & -4 \sin t \\ 5 \sin t & -4 \cos t \end{vmatrix} {\bf i}+
\begin{vmatrix} -5 \cos t & -4 \sin t \\ 5 \sin t & -4 \cos t \end{vmatrix} {\bf j}+
\begin{vmatrix} -5 \cos t & -5 \cos t \\ 5 \sin t & 5 \sin t \end{vmatrix} {\bf k} = \langle (-5\cos t)(-4\cos t)-(5\sin t)(-4\sin t), -\left( (-5\cos t)(-4 \cos t)-(5\sin t)(-4\sin t) \right), (-5\cos t)(5\sin t)-(5\sin t)(-5\cos t) \rangle$$
$$=\langle 20\cos^2 t +20\sin^2 t, -20\cos^2 t-20\sin^2 t, -25\sin t\cos t+25\sin t \cos t\rangle = \langle 20, -20, 0 \rangle$$

Using $20\cos^2 t +20\sin^2 t = 20(\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t) = 20(1) = 20$ etc.

Comment: I didn't see the way the cos and sin cancel out. But now I see, it makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the pythagorean identity.

Comment: But shouldn't it be <40,-40,0>

Comment: no, 5 * 4 = 20.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is right. In general:

(**A**x**B**)<sub>x</sub> = a<sub>y</sub>b<sub>z</sub>- a<sub>z</sub>b<sub>y</sub>
(**A**x**B**)<sub>y</sub> = a<sub>z</sub>b<sub>x</sub>- a<sub>x</sub>b<sub>z</sub>
(**A**x**B**)<sub>z</sub> = a<sub>x</sub>b<sub>y</sub>- a<sub>y</sub>b<sub>x</sub>

In this particular case:

(**r'(t)**x**r''(t)**)<sub>x</sub>=(-5cost)(-4cost)-(5sint)(-4cost)=20(sin<sup>2</sup>t+cos<sup>2</sup>t)=20

(**r'(t)**x**r''(t)**)<sub>y</sub>=(-4sint)(-5sint)-(-5cost)(-4cost)=-20(sin<sup>2</sup>t+cos<sup>2</sup>t)=-20

(**r'(t)**x**r''(t)**)<sub>z</sub>=(-5cost)(5sint)-(-5cost)(5sint)=0

Hope this helps :)